# WhenActivated not firing

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm building an app with ReactiveUI and I'm loading some values on my ViewModel using the WhenActivated subscription, but I'm facing this situation where it doesn't get fired:

```
public class MyWindow : Window, IViewFor<MyViewModel>
{
    public MyViewModelViewModel 
    { 
        get => DataContext as MainWindowViewModel; 
        set => DataContext = value; 
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel 
    { 
        get => DataContext; 
        set => DataContext = value; 
    }

    public MyView()
    {
        this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d => LoadDataAsync().ToObservable().Subscribe(
                res => { }, 
                exc => 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error ocurred on InitAsync: " + exc.Message + " - " + exc.StackTrace);
                    //HANDLE EXCEPTION
                }
                ).DisposeWith(d));
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync() => await DataBase.LoadData();
}
```

LoadDataAsync doesn't get fired unless I change View constructor for this:

```
public MyView()
{
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel();

    //If we dont' call WhenActivated on View it doesn't get called on ViewModel
    this.WhenActivated(d => { });
}
```

That way everything works as expected. Why is that? Is there any way to avoid remembering all the "WhenActivated" on each window?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to implement `ISupportsActivation` on your view model.

```
public class MyViewModel : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(d => LoadDataAsync().ToObservable().Subscribe(
                res => { }, 
                exc => 
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error ocurred on InitAsync: " + exc.Message + " - " + exc.StackTrace);
                    //HANDLE EXCEPTION
                }
                ).DisposeWith(d));
    }

    private async Task LoadDataAsync() => await DataBase.LoadData();

    // Add this property to implement the interface
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new ViewModelActivator();
}
```

This explicitly tells RxUI that your VM supports activation. I usually put this in a view model base class:

```
public class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject, ISupportsActivation
{
    public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new ViewModelActivator();
}
```

---

**Update**

According to the comments in the source code for `ISupportsActivation`, you have to call `WhenActivated` in your view to make it work.

Alternatively you could activate the VM manually by calling `MyViewModel.Activator.Activate()` (and dispose the return value when you want to deactivate), but I'm guessing that kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Yes, that was missing on the question, but actually I have it in my real code (forgot to add to the example), but it's still not working :(

Comment: I've updated my answer with details from the source code. Basically, you have to call `WhenActivated` in the view or activate the VM manually

Comment: Hi, I am calling `WhenActivated` from the view, and the VM couterpart never fires.